# Nasdaq IPO data scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, screen-scraping, nasdaq-api

I'm trying to use this code to scrape IPOs data from nasdaq webpage.

The code can scrap, but the result in my DataFrame is NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

# Define dates
start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 5, 31)
dates = pd.period_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company Name', 'Symbol', 'Market', 'Price', 'Shares'])

# Set the URL and headers
url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/activity.aspx?tab=pricings&month=%s'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'non-profit learning project'}

# Scrape IPO data for each date
for idx in dates:
    print(f'Fetching data for {idx}')
    result = requests.get(url % idx, headers=headers)
    sleep(30)
    content = result.content
    
    if 'There is no data for this month' not in str(content):
        table = pd.read_html(content)[0]
        print(table)
        df = pd.concat([df, table], ignore_index=True)
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")
        
        links = soup.find_all('a', id=re.compile('two_column_main_content_rptPricing_company_\d'))
        print(f"Length of table vs length of links: {table.shape[0] - len(links)}")
        
        for link in links:
            df['Link'].append(link['href'])

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

##This is the result:

```
Fetching data for 2023-01
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0         NaN         NaN
Length of table vs length of links: 1
Fetching data for 2023-02
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0         NaN         NaN
Length of table vs length of links: 1
Fetching data for 2023-03
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0         NaN         NaN
Length of table vs length of links: 1
Fetching data for 2023-04
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0         NaN         NaN
Length of table vs length of links: 1
Fetching data for 2023-05
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0         NaN         NaN
Length of table vs length of links: 1
  Company Name Symbol Market Price Shares  Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1
0          NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN
1          NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN
2          NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN
3          NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN
4          NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN         NaN         NaN
```

It seems that the code successfully fetched data for each month within the specified date range. However, there are some issues with the resulting DataFrame, as indicated by the presence of NaN values in the columns.

I want the data of the IPOs to make a model, any ideas how could that be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) and [locate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. We also [cannot offer "any ideas"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) here as this is **not a discussion forum**. "Make a model" is not an actionable task description.

Comment: For example, it appears from your existing debugging output that `pd.read_html(content)[0]` isn't giving the result you expect. So, keep digging on that. What is the result for `content`? Is that what you expect? Is it the *type* you expect? How about `pd.read_html(content)`? Why should the code `'There is no data for this month' not in str(content)` make sense - if you are trying to look for a substring, why would you need to convert to string first? If there was an error without that conversion, maybe that tells you something useful?

Comment: Did you try to check what URLs are used? Did you try to check what complete HTML responses you get back from those URLs, if you try it separately (without the processing code)? Where the code says `headers = {'User-Agent': 'non-profit learning project'}` - exactly what are you expecting the server to do with that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse HTML content but use the public API:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/ipo/calendar'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}
start_date = '2023-1-1'
end_date = '2023-5-31'
periods = pd.period_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')
dfs = []
for period in periods:
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={'date': period}).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['data']['priced'], 'rows')
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
            dealID proposedTickerSymbol                             companyName      proposedExchange proposedSharePrice sharesOffered pricedDate dollarValueOfSharesOffered dealStatus
0   1225815-104715                 BREA                      Brera Holdings PLC        NASDAQ Capital               5.00     1,705,000  1/27/2023                 $8,525,000     Priced
1    890697-104848                  TXO               TXO Energy Partners, L.P.                  NYSE              20.00     5,000,000  1/27/2023               $100,000,000     Priced
2    405880-103426                 GNLX                            GENELUX CORP        NASDAQ Capital               6.00     2,500,000  1/26/2023                $15,000,000     Priced
3   1241592-105143                  QSG                    QuantaSing Group Ltd         NASDAQ Global              12.50     3,250,000  1/25/2023                $40,625,000     Priced
4   1225290-104329                 CVKD             Cadrenal Therapeutics, Inc.        NASDAQ Capital               5.00     1,400,000  1/20/2023                 $7,000,000     Priced
..             ...                  ...                                     ...                   ...                ...           ...        ...                        ...        ...
64  1210259-102635                  SGE       Strong Global Entertainment, Inc.              NYSE MKT               4.00     1,000,000  5/16/2023                 $4,000,000     Priced
65  1254469-106197                 SLRN                          ACELYRIN, Inc.  NASDAQ Global Select              18.00    30,000,000  5/05/2023               $540,000,000     Priced
66  1239799-104989                ALCYU  Alchemy Investments Acquisition Corp 1         NASDAQ Global              10.00    10,000,000  5/05/2023               $100,000,000     Priced
67  1243360-105271                 KVUE                             Kenvue Inc.                  NYSE              22.00   172,812,560  5/04/2023             $3,801,876,320     Priced
68  1190851-101486                GODNU            Golden Star Acquisition Corp         NASDAQ Global              10.00     6,000,000  5/02/2023                $60,000,000     Priced

[69 rows x 9 columns]
```